# CakePHP Paginator with Ajax - Ajax calls aren't being called

Tags: jquery, cakephp-2.0

I'm using CakePHP's built in Paginator helper, and have struck upon a problem when trying to integrate this with Ajax.

The actual Paginator (which is this):

```
echo $this->Paginator->prev('« Previous', null, null, array('class' => 'disabled'));

echo $this->Paginator->next('Next »', null, null, array('class' => 'disabled'));
```

Works and works fine. However, it causes the page to reload, something which I don't really want to happen. Using the documentation, it said to use the following code:

```
$this->Paginator->options(array(
    'update' => '#testtable',   // This is the name of the table to be refreshed
    'evalScripts' => true
));
```

But, when I go to click the links it still just reloads the page. It completely ignores the options set. JQuery can be accessed on the page as there are other Ajax calls being called on the same page, I'm struggling to think what else is wrong?

Comment: can you post a more in depth code example? (specifically what is rendered on the result page?) if you can't figure it out in cake, you can easily intercept and correct the problem in javascript :)

Comment: please add your Javascript code used for datatable, I think that will be helpful for debugging.

Comment: @Ryan - I will update it soon, although no errors are given.

Comment: @gvLearner - The code is generated by CakePHP itself, it's not code I have written.

Answer (score 0):

Add the following script in your view file or layout file and try

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {  
  jQuery('#example').dataTable( {
    "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
    "bProcessing": true,
    "bServerSide": true,
    "sAjaxSource": src="<?= $this->base;?>/controller/action/<?=$dataId;?>",    
});
```

This may add the Ajax functionality to the pagination.

I would recommend you to use the cakephp plugin [Cakephp-DataTable](https://github.com/tigrang/cakephp-datatable)

This plugin has implemented the pagination and it has most of the features by default. They have also provided documentation and if you find any difficulty in implementing please go throught the [issues section](https://github.com/tigrang/cakephp-datatable/issues/5#issuecomment-5229179)

Also the developer is very responsive and can get clarifications for that plugin if you have any.

Answer (score 0):

I run into the same problem before. What i did was to create my own jquery bind function instead. I get rid of the `$this->Paginator->options()`

```
      $('.prev a, .next a').bind('click', function(event){
        event.preventDefault();

        var url_link = $(this).attr('href');
        $.ajax ({ async:true, 
            beforeSend: function (XMLHttpRequest) {$("#busy-indicator").fadeIn();}, 
            complete: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus) {$("#busy-indicator").fadeOut();}, 
            dataType: "html", evalScripts:true, 
            success: function (data, textStatus) {   
                $("#testtable").empty().html(data);
            }, 
            url: url_link});
            return false;

        });
```

Comment: In your view if you're calling an external script it should look something like this.  `<?php echo $this->Html->script('jqueryfile'); ?>` Please note that your script should be inline and not put in the head.